# What do we call a set of Gaussians with the same covariance matrix?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, terminology

What do we call a set of Gaussian distributions with the same covariance but different means?

Is there a particular term for that?

I mean the Gaussians are like:

$N(\mu_1,\Sigma), N(\mu_2,\Sigma), N(\mu_3,\Sigma)...$

Comment: Do you mean with the same variances and with all covariances between pairs of different variables the same?

Comment: @Glen_b yes, all the same, the only difference is the mean.

Comment: Wait, I thought you were talking about common values within a single $\Sigma$. So the common $\Sigma$ is an arbitrary covariance matrix?

Comment: @Glen_b sorry I misunderstood, yes $\Sigma$ is just an arbitrary covariance matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When different multivariate distributions have the same covariance matrix, you could describe them as having "common covariance structure" or "a common covariance matrix, $\Sigma$".

You could perhaps try a term like "equi-covariant" but I don't think I've seen such a term used, and it might not be understood.